# Pass PHP var to js function

Tags: javascript, php, function, dom-events

I would like to pass a var from PHP to Javascript. I did this but it does not work. Can someone help me? If you tell me where I'm wrong I learn.

```
<script>
    var passo = <?php echo 'hello'; ?>;
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="funzionepassaggio(passo)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalSubmit"><?php echo "empty"; ?></button>

<script>
      function funzionepassaggio(pass) {
          alert("hello" + pass);
      }
    </script>
```

The answer is `hello undefined`.

I have one other question! The variable that I have to pass is located within a loop, and of course he always passes the last value! How can I do so that has passed the value that the variable at that time? This is the code:

```
for ($a = 0; $a < 2; $a = $a + 1) {
          ?>
            <td>
                <script>
                    var passo = "<?php echo $rigauno->nome; ?>";
                </script>
                <button type="button" onclick="funzionepassaggio(passo)" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalSubmit"><?php echo "vuoto"; ?></button>
            </td>
        <?php }  ?>
```

Comment: If you are trying to pass some paramter to JavaScript function by setting php value to that paramter, then you can directly do it by ``onclick="funzionepassaggio(<?php $phpVariableHere ?> )"``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to incude the quotes, so it will be valid string:

```
<script>
    var passo = "<?php echo 'hello'; ?>";
</script>
```

or better call json_encode that will convert whatever you pass as JSON:

```
<script>
    var passo = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

json_enocde variable which you want to pass

```
<script>
  var passo = <?php echo json_encode('hello'); ?>;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$pass='your string or your value ';
<button type="button" onclick="funzionepassaggio('<?php echo $hello; ?>')" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ModalSubmit"><?php echo "empty"; ?></button>
<script>
  function funzionepassaggio(pass) {
      alert("hello" + pass);
  }
</script>
```